# How to do qualitative entropy aggregation in python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, entropy

Lets us assume that we have a pandas DataFrame that looks as the following:

```
|-----------|----------|-----|
| member_id | group_id | pet |
|-----------|----------|-----|
| 111       | aaa      | cat |
| 222       | aaa      | dog |
| 333       | aaa      | cat | 
| 444       | aaa      | rat |
| 555       | bbb      | cat |
| 666       | bbb      | cat |
| 777       | bbb      | dog |
| 888       | bbb      | dog |
| 999       | ccc      | rat |
|-----------|----------|-----|
```

I would like to calculate a measure of the variance of data in the pet column (qualitative data), grouped by group_id.

So the result would be (using Shannon entropy with natural log as our metric):

```
|----------|-------------|
| group_id | pet_entropy | 
|----------|-------------|
| aaa      | 1.03972     |
| bbb      | 0.69315     |
| ccc      | 0           |
|----------|-------------|
```

Can anybody suggest an elegant way to do this?

I know that it is possible to define custom aggregation functions, but I can't get my head round how to achieve it for this example. I have also tried using the scipy.stats.entropy function but it didn't seem to work on the qualitative data.

So far I am thinking of using Shannon entropy as my variance measure, though would be very interested to hear of any other recommended metrics for variance of qualitative data.